# Maximum matchings in a bipartite graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How can I show that a bipartite graph $G=G(X,Y),V(G)=X \bigcup Y$ has a perfect matching  iff $\mid N_{G}(S)\mid  \geq \mid S\mid  $ for all $S \subset V(G)$, where $V(G)$ are the vertices of $G,$ $S$ is a set of vertices $S \subset V(G)=X \bigcup Y $ in $G$ and  $N_{G}(S)=\{y \in Y \mid \exists x \in S, xy \in E(G) \}$ the set of all neighbours of vertices of $S$, where $E(G)$ are the edges of $G$. The Hall condition is helping me in any way ?

Comment: This is precisely the [Hall condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall's_marriage_theorem#Graph_theoretic_formulation).

Comment: There's a difference. The Hall condition is $\mid N_{G}(S)\mid \geq \mid S \mid$ for all $S \subset X$ and I have for all $S \subset V(G)$.

Comment: But you said "$S$ is a set of vertices $S\subset X$".

Comment: I understand. But if $S \subset V(G)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $|N_G (S)| \geq |S|$ for all $S \in V(G)$, and $X$ is a subset of $V$, we can say that the condition $|N_G (S)| \geq |S|$ is satisfied by all $S \in X$. By Hall's theorem, it has a perfect matching.

Given there's a perfect matching, we can say that $\forall S \in X,|N_G (S)| \geq |S| $ and $\forall S \in Y,|N_G (S)| \geq |S| $. Given any subset $S_0$ of $V(G)$, we can write $S_0 = S_1 \cup S_2$ where $S_1 \in X$ and $S_2 \in Y$. And since $S_1$ and $S_2$ has no intersection and it's a bipartite graph, $|N_G (S_1)|$ and $|N_G (S_2)|$ also has no intersection. So $|N_G(S_0)| = |N_G (S_1)| + |N_G (S_2)| \geq |S_1| + |S_2| = |S+0|$.

So it is a "if and only if" statement.